# IsDebuggerPresent returns true on a standard customer PC

Tags: debugging, msdn

I'm using IsDebuggerPresent call inside my software code, when I works under my IDE to test and display some part of the data to understand what is happening. When my software is located on the customer PC, this later never sees all this debug information (nothing is displayed) because IsDebuggerPresent returns false.

But I have a user that does nothing special, never use any IDE to debug any software, as a standard basic user and my software returns IsDebuggerPresent as true on his machine. So he sees a lot of stuff that he should not, and make him confused.
This is something I do not understand why IsDebuggerPresent returns true in this case. It means that my application runs into a "context of a debugger". This is a large 32 bits application. The PC of the customer is a Huawei brand; I do not know if it is a reason. If I compile my software as 64 bits target image, IsDebuggerPresent returns false in this case, and looks OK.